# Ajax call to submit text into database don't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a page where users can put comments below photos, everything works fine in php, comments go to the database and displayed below the photo.
Now I'm trying to make it work with ajax but I have some troubles.

I have an **javascript** document with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){

    var update = $("#activitymessage").val()

   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/save_comment.php",
        //data: { update: update}, - first version, not correct
        data: { activitymessage: update},
        datatype: 'json'

    })
     .done(function(response) {
            console.log("ajax done");
            console.log (response.message);


         var ht = "<li>" + update + "</li>";
         $("#listupdates").append(ht);
        });

    e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

The **php** page (save_comment.php) where I tell what to do with the input text:

```
<?php
 spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
 include_once("../classes/" . $class . ".class.php");
 });

$activity = new Comment();


if (!empty($_POST['activitymessage'])) {
$activity->Text = $_POST['activitymessage'];


try {
    //$activity->idPost = $_GET['nr'];
    //$activity->idUser = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    // with this it works, but not yet correct
    $activity->idPost = 66;
    $activity->idUser = 3;

    $activity->SavePost();
    $response['status'] = 'succes';
    $response['message'] = 'Update succesvol';


} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    $response['status'] = "error";
    $response['message'] = $feedback;


}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

There is also the file Comment.class.php with the 'Comment' class and the function SavePost(). This works without ajax, so I assume the function is correct.

What works

1. the comment (var update) is printed on the screen into the list.
2. The console says : "ajax done"

What don't work

1. The input text don't insert into the database (and disappears when page refresh)
2. The console says:  "undefined"  (there must be something wrong with the 'response I use in this function)

I hope you guys can help me out. Thanx

---

**update**
I changed the:  data: { activitymessage: update}  line in the js file, and set manually values for the $activity->idPost = 66; $activity->idUser = 3; And everything works !

Only one thing I want to get fixed

1. the values of the $_GET['nr'] and $_SESSION['user_id'] are now set manually. Is this possible to get these automatic?

The $_GET['nr'] is the id of the page were the photo is and the comments. In this way I can make a query that returns all comments for this page.

The $_SESSION['user_id'] is the id of the user,so I can echo the username and profile photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending data with the key being `update` not `activitymessage`

Change data to:

```
data: { activitymessage: update}
```

Or change `$_POST['activitymessage']` to `$_POST['update']`

---

Also you have no `$_GET['nr']` in url used for ajax. Nothing shown would help us sort that out but you would need the url to look more like:

```
url: "./ajax/save_comment.php?nr=" + nrSourceValue,
```

Not sure why you need to use  `$_GET['nr']` and don't use `$_POST` for that also and and `nr` property to data object being sent

Comment: This is correct. Also, the reason the OP is getting undefined in the console is because of the first point. $_POST['activitymessage'] was not set, so it skips the part where $response is set. He may want to add an else to that if statement to set `$response['message'] = 'Comment not provided';`

Comment: Thanx @charlietfl , I've updated my question with the info you gave me. 
The $_GET['nr'] is the id of the page (post.php?nr=66) where I can set a comment.
I think the only thing I need now to complete this code is to import the GET and SESSIONS into javascript, and send them to the php page, What would be a good method to do this ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense...session is stored on server